# use Textview.setText in other method Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

How i can use textview value in other method?  I want to intent value of "txtTitle.setText" to other activity (cars) but i can't use that on onclick method .

```
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
       LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
       View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_list, null, true);

       TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
       txtTitle.setText(companyname[position]);

    txtTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Cars.class);
            intent.putExtra("carId", txtTitle.getText());
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Please edit my code 
 thanks

Comment: Please clarify clearly what you want to do. send the value of textview to another activity?

Comment: yes but textview is changed with  txtTitle.setText(companyname[position]) for example when postion is 1 , company name is ford , position is 2 company name is Benz and ... , i want to use value of txtTitle.setText in intent.putextra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your TextView `txtTile` is only know in your getView method, because you created it there - you need to declare this variable in your class, outside of any method.

Simply call:

```
TextView txtTitle;
```

and in `getView` you set it like this:

```
 txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
```

Comment: Is it necessary to write context.startActivity(intent);
instead of startActivity(intent); ?

Comment: thank u so much but that send just one of company name . why  txtTitle.setText(companyname[position]) not work?

Comment: I assume that you are in an adapter - then yes, it is necessary to call startActivity on your context, since an Adapter knows no method `startActivity`

Answer (score 0):

You can not use it that way, the scope of the `txtTitle`  is reduced to the method `getView` ([see](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html)), instead you should define the `TextView` as a global field and so you can use it wherever you want/ need.